# check if a dataset exists on mainfame using java ftp

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe

Has anybody used the `ftp.changeWorkingDirectory` command for mainframe datasets. This command returns true when there is a dataset. It also returns true when there is no dataset. Can you share any sample java ftp code if you have any that you use to deal with mainframe datasets. Here is the code I have that does not work.

```
public static FTPFile[] GetListOfMembersFromPDS(String pdsname, String serverN) {

FTPSClient ftp = FTPConnect(serverN);

FTPFile[] files = null;

boolean success = false;

try {
success = ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(pdsname);

if (!success) {

throw new IOException("Unable to change working directory to " + pdsname
+ " for ftp transfer with ftp client = " + ftp + ". " + ftp.getReplyString());

}

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();`enter code here`

}

System.out.println(success);

try {

files = ftp.listFiles();

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

return files;
}
```

Comment: What Java Framework are you using for FTP ... doesn't look like Apache Commons.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the working directory in a z/OS dataset environment will generally return true, unless you specify a qualifier that is too long, or the whole name is too long. That does not indicated that the working directory exists or not, as mainframe datasets don't work on a directory structure.

If you change to a "working directory" that doesn't exist yet, you will get this response:

250 "THIS.IS.THE.WORKING.DIRECTOR." is the working directory name prefix.

If you try with a name that is invalid, you'll get false.

501 A qualifier in "THIS.IS.THE.WORKING.DIRECTORY" is more than 8 characters

If you try with a name that is too long, you'll get false.

501 Invalid directory name - too large.

So relying on the boolean from changeWorking Directory won't work. You'll need to look at the reply string with the "getReplyString()" method and then parse it.

A loadlib PDS will say something like
250-The working directory may be a load library
250 The working directory "GAME.LOADLIB" is a partitioned data set

A non-loadlib PDS will just say

250 The working directory "GAME.COBOL" is a partitioned data set.

listFiles, listDirectories and ListNames have different behaviours too.

I have a number of datasets which are GAME.SRCE, GAME.COPYLIB, GAME.LOADLIB and GAME.LOADLIB.PDSE. All of them are partitioned datasets. If you change directory to GAME, and do listNames(), you get all 4. If you listFiles or listDirectories, you ONLY get the COPYLIB and the SRCE. If you change directory to GAME.SRCE, then all three methods will list all the members. If you change directory to GAME.LOADLIB, then ONLY listNames will list the members. You also do not know that GAME.LOADLIB.PDSE exists.

This was done using Apache Commons, commons-net-3.6.jar and z/OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example I found by searching.  You should see success=false if the directory can't be changed:

```
    // Change working directory
    success = ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(pdsname);
    String[] replies = ftp.getReplyStrings();
    if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
        for (String aReply : replies) {
            System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
        }
    }
    if (success) {
        System.out.println("Successfully changed working directory.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to change working directory to " + pdsname + ". See server's reply.");
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately success always returns true whether the dataset is there or not. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Not sure.  I'm not familiar with what "mainframe datasets" are.  Do they appear as folders?  You are just trying to change directories and that is not working, right?  Check what the server reply is when you change the directory.  See if there is a newer version of the FTP library than the one you are using.

Comment: They have names but not in a directory structure. The closest thing to "folders" are "Partitioned Data Sets"  which also come as Extended (PDSE).

Dataset names are in the form QUAL1.QUAL2.QUAL3.
If you refer to a "PDS member" (which is like a file in a folder) then this is be QUAL1.QUAL2.QUALI3(MEMBER).

If you change directory to QUAL1 and then list files, you will get everything starting with that. QUAL1.QUAL2 may not exist but can be created. If you list QUAL1.QUAL2.QUAL3 and it is a PDS, you will get all members, but not other datasets.

FTP will tell a client if you are in a PDS.

Comment: Mainframe FTP also works in two modes, where you can start in either dataset mode like I describe above, or in more traditional UNIX/Windows type directory mode.

Comment: If you change the working directory to a PDS, you will get this reply string.

'250 The working directory "THIS.IS.A.PDS" is a partitioned data set'

I'm having firewall troubles so I'll get some more done later.

Comment: I've found some interesting issues with this. I have a number of datasets which are GAME.SRCE, GAME.COPYLIB, GAME.LOADLIB and GAME.LOADLIB.PDSE. All of them are partitioned datasets.

If you change directory to GAME, and do listNames(), you get all 4. If you listFiles or listDirectories, you ONLY get the COPYLIB and the SRCE.

If you change directory to GAME.SRCE, then all three methods will list all the members. If you change directory to GAME.LOADLIB, then ONLY listNames will list the members. You also do not know that GAME.LOADLIB.PDSE exists.